# How do I conditionally wrap a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that will sometimes need to be rendered as an `<anchor>` and other times as a `<div>`. The `prop` I read to determine this, is `this.props.url`.

If it exists, I need to render the component wrapped in an `<a href={this.props.url}>`. Otherwise it just gets rendered as a `<div/>`.

Possible?

This is what I'm doing right now, but feel it could be simplified:

```
if (this.props.link) {
    return (
        <a href={this.props.link}>
            <i>
                {this.props.count}
            </i>
        </a>
    );
}

return (
    <i className={styles.Icon}>
        {this.props.count}
    </i>
);
```

Comment: You can also move `const baseClasses =` into that `if (this.props.link)` branch. As you are using ES6, so you can also simplify a bit by `const {link, className} = this.props;` and then using `link` and `className` as local variables.

Comment: Man, I love it. Learning more and more about ES6 and it always just improves readability. Thanks for the extra tip!

Comment: What's a "final lockup"?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Just use a variable.

```
var component = (
    <i className={styles.Icon}>
       {this.props.count}
    </i>
);

if (this.props.link) {
    return (
        <a href={this.props.link} className={baseClasses}>
            {component}
        </a>
    );
}

return component;
```

or, you can use a helper function to render the contents. JSX is code like any other. If you want to reduce duplications, use functions and variables.

Comment: This code will unmount component and recreate it on next render. You can add key="theSameKey" but this will change nothing. React.useMemo cannot cache you component and it will be unmounted. https://medium.com/@cowi4030/optimizing-conditional-rendering-in-react-3fee6b197a20

Comment: @sytolk Not really. That will happen only if your hierarchy changes. And that's only to be expected. The article you mention calls it an antipattern which it is not. And that article is also blatantly wrong about react DOM diffing.

Comment: yes this is anti pattern - look at JSX <component> exist twice and if you change props.link on next render React will unmount component. For this case its acceptable but what about if component is a heavy?

Comment: @sytolk Wrapping or not wrapping by link means you have to change hierarchy and there is no way around it. It's something you have to think about when designing your hierarchy but that does not mean it's an antipattern. I would argue that in many cases it's actually the only viable option.

Comment: @sytolk the article you mentioned is talking about conditional rendering of children but here we are talking about the wrapper/parent. these are two different things.

Answer (score 50):

Create a HOC (higher-order component) for wrapping your element:

```
const WithLink = ({ link, className, children }) => (link ?
  <a href={link} className={className}>
    {children}
  </a>
  : children
);

return (
  <WithLink link={this.props.link} className={baseClasses}>
    <i className={styles.Icon}>
      {this.props.count}
    </i>
  </WithLink>
);
```

Comment: HOC should die slowly :P

Comment: This is not an HOC. From the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html): "Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component." Here, `WithLink` is simply a component. This example makes it seem as if it is being declared within another component which is almost always a bad idea since it will be recreated on every render, meaning children will be constantly remounted.

Answer (score 45):

Here's an example of a helpful component I've seen used before (not sure who to accredit it to). It's arguably more declarative:

```js
const ConditionalWrap = ({ condition, wrap, children }) => (
  condition ? wrap(children) : children
);
```

**Use case:**

```
// MaybeModal will render its children within a modal (or not)
// depending on whether "isModal" is truthy
const MaybeModal = ({ children, isModal }) => {
  return (
    <ConditionalWrap
      condition={isModal}
      wrap={(wrappedChildren) => <Modal>{wrappedChildren}</Modal>}
    >
        {children}
    </ConditionalWrap>
  );
}
```

Comment: Credit should likely go here: https://gist.github.com/kitze/23d82bb9eb0baabfd03a6a720b1d637f

Comment: I saw that from kitze. But I wasn't sure he got the idea from someone else

Comment: Neither am I. This was the first result that popped up and I assumed it to be the source - or at least closer to it ;).

Comment: You should use the `wrap` declaratively and not as a function to keep things more "React"-spirit

Comment: How would you make it more declarative @vsync? I thought render props were within the spirit of React?

Comment: This is not [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) method, but "props" rendering, which is different

Comment: I've seen it used well before the date of that post @AlexanderFlenniken, Kitze's gist is dated from 2018

Comment: Looks like a render prop to me. From the docs: _The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between React components using a prop whose value is a function._ In this case, the value of the `wrap` prop is a function. In this case, though, the `wrap` render prop is applied conditionally.

Comment: This might be where it originated from: https://blog.hackages.io/conditionally-wrap-an-element-in-react-a8b9a47fab2

Comment: @dmikester1 the gist above predates that article by a few years.

Answer (score 26):

There's another way
you could use a reference variable

```
let Wrapper = React.Fragment //fallback in case you dont want to wrap your components

if(someCondition) {
    Wrapper = ParentComponent
}

return (
    <Wrapper parentProps={parentProps}>
        <Child></Child>
    </Wrapper>

)
```

Comment: You can condense the first half to `let Wrapper = someCondition ? ParentComponent : React.Fragment`

Comment: This is awesome, but sometimes you want to keep the code *declarative*, meaning it returns only JSX

Comment: I get an ***error*** `React.Fragment can only have 'key' and 'children'` because I pass some props to "<Wrapper>" like *"className"* and so

Comment: @vsync you need to add a condition for props as well
something like propId={someCondition? parentProps: undefined} ..

Comment: I know :) I was writing this for the sake of documentation for others who come here with this issue, so Google will cache this page in its search results for those keywords

Answer (score 8):

```
const ConditionalWrapper = ({ condition, wrapper, children }) => 
  condition ? wrapper(children) : children;
```

The component you wanna wrap as

```
<ConditionalWrapper
   condition={link}
   wrapper={children => <a href={link}>{children}</a>}>
   <h2>{brand}</h2>
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

Maybe this article can help you more
https://blog.hackages.io/conditionally-wrap-an-element-in-react-a8b9a47fab2

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a util function like this:

```
const wrapIf = (conditions, content, wrapper) => conditions
        ? React.cloneElement(wrapper, {}, content)
        : content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSX if-else as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html). Something like this should work.

```
App = React.creatClass({
    render() {
        var myComponent;
        if(typeof(this.props.url) != 'undefined') {
            myComponent = <myLink url=this.props.url>;
        }
        else {
            myComponent = <myDiv>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {myComponent}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional component which renders 2 components, one is wrapped and the other isn't.

### Method 1:

```js
// The interesting part:
const WrapIf = ({ condition, With, children, ...rest }) => 
  condition 
    ? <With {...rest}>{children}</With> 
    : children

 
    
const Wrapper = ({children, ...rest}) => <h1 {...rest}>{children}</h1>


// demo app: with & without a wrapper
const App = () => [
  <WrapIf condition={true} With={Wrapper} style={{color:"red"}}>
    foo
  </WrapIf>
  ,
  <WrapIf condition={false} With={Wrapper}>
    bar
  </WrapIf>
]

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This can also be used like this:

```
<WrapIf condition={true} With={"h1"}>
```

### Method 2:

```js
// The interesting part:
const Wrapper = ({ condition, children, ...props }) => condition 
  ? <h1 {...props}>{children}</h1>
  : <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;   
    // stackoverflow prevents using <></>
  

// demo app: with & without a wrapper
const App = () => [
  <Wrapper condition={true} style={{color:"red"}}>
    foo
  </Wrapper>
  ,
  <Wrapper condition={false}>
    bar
  </Wrapper>
]

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using react and Typescript**

```js
let Wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <>{children} </>

if (this.props.link) {
    Wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => <Link to={this.props.link}>{children} </Link>
}

return (
    <Wrapper>
        <i>
            {this.props.count}
        </i>
    </Wrapper>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

With provided solutions there is a problem with performance:
https://medium.com/@cowi4030/optimizing-conditional-rendering-in-react-3fee6b197a20

React will unmount `<Icon>` component on the next render.
`Icon` exist twice in different order in JSX and React will unmount it if you change `props.link` on next render. In this case `<Icon>` its not a heavy component and its acceptable but if you are looking for an other solutions:

https://codesandbox.io/s/82jo98o708?file=/src/index.js

https://thoughtspile.github.io/2018/12/02/react-keep-mounted/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin I have publish answer for this question why its important and users needs to keep in mind this. I think that description is enough and its not link only answer but if you want to say something more.. feels free to Edit it.

Comment: Icon gets unmounted in any case since the parent will be changed