# React/JSX - changing element type conditionally with minimal code duplication

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have something that is:

```
<div>
  {/* a lot of code */}
</div>
```

But if some condition is true, I want it to be:

```
<tr>
  {/* same code as before */}
</tr>
```

Is there any way to achieve this without a huge amount of code duplication from copy pasting?

Comment: Functions. Why dont you wrap the whole thing inside into a function?

Comment: Good call, that worked fine for me.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710833/how-do-i-conditionally-wrap-a-react-component/33710901#33710901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could render the content in a variable using `React.Fragment` and choose the enclosing element depending on the condition.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { condition: true };

  render() {
    const { condition } = this.state;
    const content = (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <h2>This is a lot of text...</h2>
      </Fragment>
    );

    return condition ? <div> {content} </div> : <tr> {content} </tr>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work well if there's many attributes (on div and tr) that you also would not wish to copy-paste

Answer (score 5):

Marked someone else as accepted answer, but the solution I ended up using was to call `React.createElement(condition ? "div" : "tr", {attribute: stuff}, <div>Inner content</div>)`. Just an alternative for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future :)

Comment: You should be able to write that without using `createElement()`, as that function is normally only needed if not doing JSX

Answer (score 1):

Add your code inside the function

```
function returnView() {
  render (
  // a lot of code
);
}
```

if condition is true call that function

```
condition? returnView() : ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with **createElement()** method? It works well for me.
So the code is:

```
import { createElement } from 'react';

createElement(type, props, ...children)
```

Example:

```
function Element({ condition, children, onClick }) {

  if (condition) {
    return createElement(
      'div',
      { className: 'element-style' },
      children
    );
  }

  return createElement(
    'tr',
    { className: 'element-style' },
    children
  );
}
```

If you have some of the special props and the rest of them is same, you can pass it in object variable

```
function Element({ condition, children, onClick }) {

  const elementProps = {
    className: 'element-style',
    onClick,
  };

  if (condition) {
    return createElement(
      'div',
      { ...elementProps, style: { color: 'white' } },
      children
    );
  }

  return createElement(
    'tr',
    { ...elementProps, style: { color: 'black' } },
    children
  );
}
```

Source: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement

Answer (score 1):

**Create a component like this**

```
const ContentContainer = ({as, children, ...props}) => {
    return React.createElement(as ?? 'div', ...props, ...children)
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ContentContainer as="tr" className="main-container">
     // a lot of code
</ContentContainer>
```