# Learner Question: How to conditionally set wrapper for this particular code. React/SPFX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, spfx

I'm trying to apply a `<Fade />` to a block of code in the render but only if this.state.ContextNewJobFade is false.

I've read [How do I conditionally wrap a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710833/how-do-i-conditionally-wrap-a-react-component) completely and still don't know how to implement it with my code. EDIT post solution: I believe this question is VERY similar to the one above but it uses a Fade wrapper instead of a href link.

Here's the block from the render:

```
<div>
{this.state.ContextNewJobFade === false ?
  <Fade>
    <Label className={styles.questionTitle1}>Text:</Label>
    <br />

    <div className={styles.questionDescription}>
      Text
      <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <TextField
      name="txtContextNewJobCode"
      multiline
      resizable={false}
      value={this.state.ContNewJobCode}
      onChange={this._onContNewJobCodeChng}
    />
  </Fade>
) : (
  <div>
    <Label className={styles.questionTitle1}>Some Text</Label>
    <br />

    <div className={styles.questionDescription}>
      Text
      <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <TextField
      name="txtContextNewJobCode"
      multiline
      resizable={false}
      value={this.state.ContNewJobCode}
      onChange={this._onContNewJobCodeChng}
    />
  </div>
);
```

As you can see I'm duplicating the code here and need a better solution.

Comment: Just put the duplicate content in a variable. `const content = <div>duplicate content</div>;` and in your render, insert it where necessary. `{condition ? <div className="wrapper">{content}</div> : content}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how i would refactor your components, hope it helps!

```js
const FadeComponent = ({ fade, children }) =>
  fade ? <Fade>{children}</Fade> : children;

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <FadeComponent fade={this.state.ContextNewJobFade}>
      <Label className={styles.questionTitle1}>Text:</Label>
      <br />

      <div className={styles.questionDescription}>
        Text
        <br />
      </div>
      <br />
      <TextField
        name='txtContextNewJobCode'
        multiline
        resizable={false}
        value={this.state.ContNewJobCode}
        onChange={this._onContNewJobCodeChng}
      />
    </FadeComponent>
  );
};
```

Comment: Getting: JSX element type 'Element | { children: any; }' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type '{ children: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Comment: Hmm, might be the curly braces on children. Let me edit that real quick and see if that works

Comment: yes that's worked, as the code is, (with curly braces in the arguments for <FadeComponent>.

Comment: So the fade argument is for the state variable (in this case), and the children is everything within the FadeComponents encapsulation?
Is this an HOC?

Comment: So the value that's passed into FadeComponent is called props and yes, everything wrapped within the FadeComponent would be the children.